# Size selection is not displayed, returns text Size

Tags: magento2

I created a configuration product and attached simple products with dimensions to it. When switching to a product, the selection of sizes is not displayed, but the text is displayed.

[image]

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: can you please add proper way like weight value add in simple product.

Answer (score 0):

This feature helped me if I enabled it

go to

Stores > Product > Size > Storefront Properties

[image]